# Recebendo valor de um método para outro - Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Eu preciso receber o valor que vem das configurações do aparelho (Que eu já consegui, como está no código abaixo) e preciso passar esse retorno para uma string que vai permitir o login ao meu aplicativo, dê uma olhada no código:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* txt = [defaults objectForKey:@"txtEmail"];
```

O código acima está no **AppDelegate.m** (Dentro da pasta chamada Baker), e é por esse trecho que eu estou pegando as informações que foram configuradas no aparelho, até aqui tudo bem, está funcionando certo. O problema é que eu preciso passar essa variável **'txt'** para outra classe (se é que posso chamar assim) chamada **Constants.h** (Está na pasta chamada BakerShelf) e colocar nesse trecho de código:

```
#define NEWSSTAND_MANIFEST_URL @"[link_do_site]?digitha_userid=[txt]
```

Substituindo o **[txt]** pelo valor recebido do primeiro trecho.

Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade como é uma constante, você não pode mudar o valor dela, porque no momento da definição você não possui o valor do "txt", você teria que ao utilizar o valor, criar uma nova NSString dando replace no placeholder. De uma olhada em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668228/string-replacement-in-objective-c.

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda, isso vai ser útil, mas minha dificuldade está em trazer a variável de um arquivo para outro. Uma variável está declarada no AppDelegate.m, e eu preciso usar ela no Constants.h. Sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi da semântica do arquivo `Constants.h` é que outros arquivos usem ele, e não o contrário. Logo você teria que dar um include nele (`Contants.h`) de dentro do `AppDelegate.m` (de uma olhada em http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c) e ai poderá usar tudo que foi declarado no `header`.

Comment: Ótimo! Consegui obter os valores e colocar na string. Mas pelo que vc falou então eu não vou conseguir colocar essa string de volta nesse trecho de código `#define NEWSSTAND_MANIFEST_URL @"[link_do_site]?digitha_userid=[txt]` ? Pq eu preciso que a minha string alterada volte para o Constants.h para ser usada nesse #define, não tem nhm meio de eu fazer isso?

Comment: Já que eu já tenho a string organizada, não tem como eu fazer algo assim: `#define NEWSSTAND_MANIFEST_URL = variavel`?

Comment: Conheço duas formas: Em vez usar define, declare ela como `static` (tendo um template usando define). Ou coloque ela nas preferencias do usuário depois de fazer o replace.

Comment: Criei como `static` e o código ficou assim `static NSString *NEWSSTAND_MANIFEST_URL = urlTxt`. Porém ele da um erro "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant"." Pelo que eu entendi, esse `Constants.h`é um arquivo que vai ser lido antes da execução do programa, então tudo deve ser estático, e não da para usar variáveis. Teria alguma sugestão de como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver o problema criando uma variável global com a string, e dando replace nas partes que eu precisava editar, funcionou sem problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, estive com um problema parecido com o seu, estava tentando armazenar dados gerados em uma classe e passar para outra. A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

Vá na classe que irá receber os dados, e crie uma variável que irá guardar os dados e sua propriedade. Depois crie também um método que receba como argumento os dados que você quer guardar, e dentro do método faça ele ser armazenado na variável que você criou.

No arquivo ClasseOrigemDados.m, coloque o #import "ClasseQueArmazena.h" e instancie um objeto da classe que irá receber os dados, e passe o valor que vc quer no argumento do método.

Como no código de exemplo que vou fazer abaixo para ficar melhor ilustrado.

```
*** ClasseQueRecebeDados.h ***

import<UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClasseQueRecebeDados : NSObject{

 NSString* receptor;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* receptor;

-(void)metodoTransfereDados:(NSString*)dadosRecebido;

@end
```

No arquivo ClasseQueRecebeDados.m você implementa esse método da seguinte maneira:

```
#import "ClasseQueRecebeDados.h"

@implementation ClasseQueRecebeDados

@syntesize receptor;

-(void)metodoTransfereDados:(NSString*)dadosRecebido{

 self.receptor = dadosRecebido;
}

@end
```

Agora em ClasseQueForneceDados.m você faz assim:

```
// Importe a classe para instanciar um objeto dela e ter acesso ao seu método.
    #import "ClasseQueRecebeDados.h"

      @implementation ClasseQueForneceDados

    -(void)DentroDeAlgumMetodoDaClasseQueForneceDados{

     ClasseQueRecebeDados* armazenador = [[ClasseQueRecebeDados alloc]init];

      // Aqui você instancia a classe ClasseQueRecebeDados e usa o método.
     [armazenador metodoTransfereDados: self.dadoQueSeráEnviadoHaOutraClasse];

    }
    (DEMAIS CODIGO DA IMPLEMENTAÇÂO ...)

    @end
```

Ao usar o método, você enviará os dados para às variáveis do objeto que você instanciou.  Dentro do método, acredito que será mais útil guardar os dados em uma plist, do que ter ele somente na memória do app, deste modo os dados ficarão visíveis de vários pontos do app.

Espero que tenha ajudado, qualquer dúvida basta comentar abaixo!

Comment: Existe também o uso de singleton. Pode ser interessante para você. Dê uma olhada nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25447/manter-objeto-vivo-na-memoria-para-outra-classe/25466#25466

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView ()

@end

NSString *Global_PESS_CODIGO;

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Constants.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

e no Appdelegate.m

```
NSString* txt = [defaults objectForKey:@"txtEmail"];

Global_PESS_CODIGO = txt;
```

depois é só importar `#import "Constants.h"` quando vc quiser usar a string

Answer (score 0):

Por que você precisa definir uma constante? Por que não criar uma classe com um método que retorna o valor?

Asim:

```
@interface Constants
+ (NSString *)newsstandManifestURLString;
@end

@implementation Constants
+ (NSString *)newsstandManifestURLString {
    NSString *txt = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"txtEmail"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[link_do_site]?digitha_userid=%@", txt];
}
@end
```