# Manter objeto vivo na memoria para outra classe

Tags: array, ios, objective-c, sqlite, sqlite3

Ola! Estou com uma dúvida muito simples, pois já encontrei uma solução para ela, mas ainda me parece problemática. Vou explicar:

Criei uma conexão com web service para receber alguns dados, e no final eu estou armazenando esses dados em um dicionário, que por sua vez fica salvo em um array.

Porém preciso que esse array seja inicializado em outro local, dentro da classe que vai salvar os dados no sqlite. Mas não sei como inicializar esse array com os dados que foram recebidos do web service.

A solução que encontrei, foi utilizar o AppDelegate. O AppDelegate teria uma variável que receberá esse array, e depois eu iria gerar uma instância de AppDelegate dentro da classe que gerencia o banco de dados sqlite. Porém, acredito que dependendo da quantidade, e do volume de dados nas tabelas, eu poderia sobrecarregar o AppDelegate, consumindo muita memória.

Alguém saberia como resolver esse problema!

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua solução é válida (utilizar o AppDelegate) porém ela é ruim do ponto de vista da orientação a objetos. Você estará colocando no AppDelegate um atributo que não está logicamente relacionado a essa classe.
Sugiro utilizar a mesma ideia (Singleton), porém criando um objeto específico para os dados compartilhados entre suas classes. Desse modo você diminui o acoplamento do código e aumenta sua coesão. Exemplo:

```
@interface SharedData : NSObject

+ (SharedData*)sharedInstance;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *nodes;

@end

@implementation SharedData

+ (SharedData *)sharedInstance
{
    static SharedData *_sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t instanceOnceToken;
    dispatch_once(&instanceOnceToken, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[SharedData alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

Nas outras classes você acessa as propriedades e métodos do singleton de forma similar como faria com o AppDelegate, isto é, através da instância compartilhada, ex:

```
[SharedData sharedInstance].nodes = [NSArray new];
```

Quanto a questão de memória, essa solução é levemente menos eficiente pois aloca um objeto adicional, mas isso não impactará na performance. Os problemas podem aparecer se você manter objetos grandes e complexos na memória, como bitmaps. Com dicionários, dificilmente terá problemas.

Comment: Então, usando o exemplo, eu teria que instanciar SharedData em um ponto para receber os dados que quero, e depois no momento que eu instanciar ela novamente em outro ponto, e ela irá ter em seu atributo os dados que passei anteriormente?

E quanto ao uso de memoria, pode ser que eu precise me preocupar, pois nestes dados que irei receber pelo web service terei sim algumas imagens. Vou verificar quanto ao tamanho delas com o responsavel do DB.

Comment: Sim, o objeto inteiro será mantido na memória durante o ciclo de vida da aplicação.Você não precisa se preocupar quanto a alocação. Ela ocorrerá na primeira vez que o Singleton for acessado.

Comment: Bom, eu fiz uma solução mais objetiva para o problema. Eu modifiquei o método da classe que gerencia o banco de dados. Fazendo que o método receba os dados e passe para a função de inserir os dados.

 Então instancio um objeto do BDManager e envio o método insertData com as propriedades(que são os valores recebido do webservice) como argumentos. E a inserção funciona 100% dentro do método!